# How to fix missing OpenSSL library for MySQL after brew upgrade?

Tags: mysql, macos, openssl, homebrew

I upgraded MySQL (and a slew of other packages) using the ever-so dangerous `brew update && brew upgrade`

After the upgrade, I started getting a database connection error in the browser and then realized **the OpenSSL library is now missing**

*My initial thought was to force uninstall OpenSSL and re-install the version MySQL is looking for, but there's quite a few packages depending on the current version.*

**Error**

```
chris$ mysql -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
  Reason: image not found
```

**OpenSSL**

[image]

**Attempt to `brew uninstall` openssl** (with intention of re-reinstalling 1.0)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to switch back:

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
```

Helped for me.